# Permalink structure with $_SESSION variables

Tags: permalinks, post-meta, meta-query, session

I have a project that has content being filtered throughout the site (many custom WP_QUERY calls). Originally there was no URL needs, just filtering by **$_SESSION** variable. Works perfectly, but NOW client wants each specialty to be loaded with a custom URL (much like categories do already). I need to to first know:

> **Is it possible to make a permalink structure with the $_SESSION variable?**

If so:

> **How can I create a URL structure like this?**

**Archive Page:**

```
http://domain.com/session-var/
```

**Single Page:**

```
http://domain.com/session-var/post-name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to figure this out myself with the help of a great friend and php developer. I apologize some of the functionality `i.e. CUSTOM::slugify()` is custom but if necessary you can review my [Div Starter theme](https://github.com/Xtremefaith/div-starter) to learn more about it.

```
add_action( 'init', 'cc_rewrite_add_rewrites' );
function cc_rewrite_add_rewrites() {
    $specialties = get_specialties(); //Fetches an array of postmeta defined from an ACF repeater field


    add_rewrite_rule( "^(" . implode("|", array_map(function($a) { return strtolower(CUSTOM::slugify($a)); }, $specialties) ) . ")/?", 'index.php', 'top' );
    flush_rewrite_rules();

    // check path for specialty loop through specialties
    foreach($specialties as $specialty) {
        $slug = CUSTOM::slugify($specialty); // I needed to convert to a slug, custom function in Div Starter

        if (preg_match("/\/" . strtolower($slug) ."(\/|$)/i", strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) )) {
        // set session variable
        $_SESSION['specialty'] = $specialty;
        break;
    }
}
```

}

I noticed my pagination was using this new permalink structure and breaking it so I was able to hook into it and remove the addition like this:

```
add_filter( 'get_pagenum_link', 'wpse_cc_pagenum_link' );

function wpse_cc_pagenum_link( $link ){
    return $url = str_replace( '/'.CUSTOM::slugify($_SESSION['specialty']), '', $link ); 
}
```

For more information about customizing your permalinks [this guide](http://pmg.co/blog/?id=a-mostly-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-rewrite-api) was really helpful